# how to filter view with "any" comparison?

Tags: couchdb

i have a database in couchdb which contain 4 documents... [here the sample](https://erdin.cloudant.com/pc/_design/dsg/_view/test)
and here is the the document source:

1. `{"_id": "...","gender": "F","hat": "BLUE"}`
2. `{"_id": "...","gender": "F","hat": "RED"}`
3. `{"_id": "...","gender": "M","hat": "BLUE"}`
4. `{"_id": "...","gender": "M","hat": "RED"}`

here is my view:

```
function(doc) {
   emit([doc.gender,doc.hat], doc);
}
```

but i want to fetch data with following case :

1. select all with gender 'F' and any kind of hat (done | [sample](https://erdin.cloudant.com/pc/_design/dsg/_view/test?startkey=%5B%22F%22,%220%22%5D&endkey=%5B%22F%22,%22ZZ%22%5D))
2. select all with any kind of gender and have "RED' hat (stack)

how to make second point works??
how to filter view with "any" comparison ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second point, you need a view like this;

```
function(doc) {
   emit(doc.hat, null);
}
```

Query with ?key="RED".

Note: I emit null to save space in the index. Query with ?include_docs=true to get the docs back.

Comment: then it means i must to make another view ??

Comment: @Robert Newson, did you mean `?key="RED"` instead of `?hat="RED"`?

Comment: yes, sorry, ?key=. And, yes, you need an index into your data for every way you wish to query it (same as an RDBMS).

Comment: You'll need one view for each ordering but sometimes you can combine views. Your original view, for example, can answer two kinds of question: 1) find all matches for a particular gender (?startkey=["M"]&endkey=["M",{}]) and 2) find all matches for a particular gender and hat color (?key=["M","RED"]).